# Dynamic components won't render corresponding templates

Tags: vue.js

I have two templates that I want to dynamically render into a component. Clicking on the corresponding nav item *should* render the relevant component, but it doesn't seem to be working for me right now.

```
<div id="app">

  <ul>
    <li v-on:click="currentView='fruits-module'"><a href="#">Fruits</a></li>
    <li v-on:click="currentView='vegetables-module'"><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
  </ul>



   <template id="fruits-template" class="module">
     <ul>
       <li v-for="fruit in fruits">{{ fruit }}</li>
     </ul>
  </template>

  <template id="vegetables-template" class="module">
     <ul>
       <li v-for="vegetable in vegetables">{{ vegetable }}</li>
     </ul>
  </template>

  <component v-bind:is="currentView"></component>


</div>
```

Here is the script portion of it. Interesting that when I do `app.currentView` in the console, it's returning `undefined`, which shouldn't be the case.

```
Vue.component('fruits-module', {
  template: '#fruits-template',
  data(){
    return{
      fruits:['apple', 'orange', 'pear']
    }
  }
})


Vue.component('vegetables-module', {
  template: '#vegetables-template',
  data(){
    return{
      vegetables:['carrots', 'spinach', 'broccoli']
    }
  }
})



new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data(){
    return {
      currentView: 'fruits-module'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Your provided codepen example is running well and no errors shown in console!

Comment: Yes, I already answered it :) See my answer below

Comment: So i wonder why does question has solution link included!

Answer (score 0):

[Relevant codepen](https://codepen.io/modermo/pen/YrQPXG?editors=1011)

I don't know why this fixes it, but I removed `template` from outside `<div id="app">` and it works. So, it should instead be:

```
<div id="app">

  <ul>
    <li v-on:click="currentView='fruits-module'"><a href="#">Fruits</a></li>
    <li v-on:click="currentView='vegetables-module'"><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
  </ul>

  <component v-bind:is="currentView"></component>

</div>  


 <template id="fruits-template" class="module">
     <ul>
       <li v-for="fruit in fruits">{{ fruit }}</li>
     </ul>
  </template>

  <template id="vegetables-template" class="module">
     <ul>
       <li v-for="vegetable in vegetables">{{ vegetable }}</li>
     </ul>
  </template>
```